# Tagging an Instantiated Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting a "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when I try to tag an object as soon as I instantiate it. The enemyAnimal object is created (it's a prefab that appears fine in the scene), but I must not be referencing it correctly, and I cannot figure out a way to either get this to work, or to tag the object as I instantiate it.

```
public void placeAnimal()
    {
        GameObject enemy = Instantiate (enemyAnimal, new Vector3 (7, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)) as GameObject;

        enemy.tag = "EnemyAnimal";
    }
```

Comment: check if enemy is null by doing if(enemy ==null){
Debug.Log("Enemy is null");
}

Report back to me

Comment: @Programmer It is null (I just checked as you have asked), but i don't understand how that's possible since I can clearly see the instantiated enemyAnimal in the scene, and this is the very next line of code after that enemyAnimal is placed.

Comment: That is the problem. Can you post code on how enemyAnimal is defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `enemy` is not a game object, and when you try to cast it to it, of course you get null. Is it a mono behavior? Cast it to it's true type (the same as `enemyAnimal` is defined with) and use `gameObject` property:

```
public void placeAnimal()
{
    var enemy = Instantiate (enemyAnimal, new Vector3 (7, 0, 0), Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0)) as MonoBehaviour;
    enemy.gameObject.tag = "EnemyAnimal";
}
```

Comment: I had thought that everything was a GameObject (that everything inherited from a GameObject) because of how many times I have set a variable to GameObject and it allowed me to put anything at all into it.  But you were absolutely right.  When I recast it as an Animal type, it worked.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Everything is not a game object. Every C# entity derives from `System.Object` class, and all Unity stuff derives from `UnityEngine.Object` class (which, too, is a child of `System.Object`. However, `MonoBehaviour` is **not** a game object. I think this might help you understand relationship between mono behaviors and components better: http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html

Comment: Outstanding.  Thank you so much.  I don't have enough reputation, I don't think, to do anything more than mark this as answered, but I really really appreciate the help and the link.  I'm diving into it now.

Comment: I will do that for you. +1